# Google Structured Data Testing Tool reports image list errors and images are not showing up in image search

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data

I have a [site](http://cineindya.com) and these days Google is not searching my images. When I open Google Webmaster Tools, I see thousands of errors in my images list.

Here is an example [link](http://www.cineindya.com/news-gossip/b-town-gorgeous-celebs-at-tempesta-luxury-launch/attachment/b-town-good-looking-girls-at-tempesta-luxury-launch/).

If I put it in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool, I get errors like:

```
Missing: author
Missing: entry-title
Missing: updated
```

I think I did everything right, which I found help for on the Internet.

Again and again it's showing me the same errors, but I'm not sure Google is taking the time to check this thing - I mean should I wait either a week or a month, or maybe I did something wrong. Please let me know if I did something wrong, or just have to wait for Google.

Comment: `<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<div>

<a href="http://google.com/profiles/111393867023881702006"><span class="fn"><span class="author"><?php the_author() ?></span></span></a>

<span>
<time datetime="2013-10-3T12:33:43+00:00" class="entry-date date updated"><?php echo get_the_date();?></time></span>

</div>`

Answer (score 1):

When I check your URL in the Structured Data Tool, I noticed you missed few things.

For the entry-title:

```
<h1 class="entry-title">Your page title here</h1>
```

You also used an `A` tag  inside an `H1` so the `entry-title` class needs to add on the `A` or avoid link.

For the Author:

```
<a href=".."><span class="fn"><span class="author">admin</span></span></a>
```

For Date

```
<time datetime="2013-10-3T12:33:43+00:00" class="entry-date date updated">October 3, 2013</time>
```

Comment: hello Jobin first thing first thanks a lot to do give me an answer, i did what you did, and checked in google structured data tool, but nothing success, same errors,

Error: Missing required field "entry-title".
Error: Missing required field "updated".
Error: Missing required hCard "author".

now i don't know whats' wrong, may be google will take in cache, or next time when google will fatch it Structured Data, may be that time it will solve, or 

may be this thing not work in wordpress attachment.php